# Flex/FlashBuilder :: Spark List / IconItemRenderer:: Disable Selection Highlight / No Selection / Remove Selection

Tags: list, apache-flex, selection, flex-spark

I had trouble removing the selected and down state colors for a spark list using IconItemRender. If you are making a mobile app and using IconItemRender (instead of ItemRenderer) there is no autoDrawBackground property.

I figured I'd drop it in here after figuring it out thanks to this page: http://www.sajeevkumar.com/2012/01/08/flex-4-6-list-mobile-iconitemrenderer-background-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to muck around with the down and selected colors.  For more control over items in a list using IconItemRender look at the LabelItemRenderer class and the drawBackground function.

```
override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

            var bgColor:uint = 0xffffff;

            graphics.clear();

            graphics.beginFill(bgColor,1);
            graphics.lineStyle();
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            graphics.endFill();

            // Draw the separator for the item renderer
            super.drawBorder(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            opaqueBackground = bgColor;
        }
```